# Wrong Address when Transfering BTC to Paper Wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet

I think I fucked up when transfering my BTC from exchange to paper wallet. 
I used the private Bitcoin address you get when u make a paper wallet instead of receive address generated in blockchain.info. The transaction was confirmed but the BTC never received. 
Where did the BTC go?

Comment: Can you link a txid? If the transaction confirmed, then it paid to whatever address you specified. If you somehow paid to a private key (I don't think this is possible?), then the BTC are lost, since you don't have a private key that will be able to sign a transaction spending those coins.

Comment: If that address is the address for your paper wallet, then yes, you should be able to recover those funds from the paper wallet, by importing the private key to a wallet you control. Note that it is important you understand how change addresses work, so that you do not accidentally lose coins. Paper wallets can be dangerous if not used correctly.